# SQL Server Left Join Counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this sample code

```
create table #Reservation
(id int identity(1,1),
 name varchar(50)
);

create table #Reservation_details
(id int identity(1,1),
 reservation_id int,
 reservation_date date,
 seated tinyint
);

create table #Payment
(id int identity(1,1),
 reservation_id int,
 payment decimal(18,2)
);

insert into #Reservation(name)
values ('Spiderman'),('Superman'),('Batman'),('Hulk');

insert into #Reservation_details(reservation_id,reservation_date,seated)
values (1,'2017-12-07',0),(2,'2017-12-08',0),(3,'2017-12-08',1),(4,'2017-12-08',0);

insert into #Payment(reservation_id,payment)
values(1,220),(2,1000)

select
 A.id,
 A.name,
 B.reservation_date,
 B.seated,
 C.payment
from #Reservation A
inner join #Reservation_details B
on B.reservation_id = A.id
left join #Payment C
on C.reservation_id = B.reservation_id
where reservation_date = '2017-12-08'

drop table #Reservation
drop table #Reservation_details
drop table #Payment
```

I wanted to get the count of all reservations where date is '2017-12-08' and seated = 1 or payment is not null

I've tried putting where date is '2017-12-08' and seated = 1 or payment is not 
null

but instead it showed me the past date also how do use where as count?

Comment: You probably just need parentheses in the boolean expression.

Comment: after the date sir?

Comment: Do `Reservation` and `Reservation_details` have 1-1 relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
select COUNT(*)
from #Reservation A
inner join #Reservation_details B on B.reservation_id = A.id
left join #Payment C on C.reservation_id = B.reservation_id
where reservation_date = '2017-12-08'
  and (B.seated=1 or C.payment is not null)
```

I think you forgot to use brackets `(condition1 OR condition2)` for `OR` operation.

See operator precedence - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql

In your case if you don't use brackets then

```
reservation_date = '2017-12-08' and B.seated=1 or C.payment is not null
```

equals the following

```
(reservation_date = '2017-12-08' and B.seated=1) or C.payment is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
A.id,
A.name,
B.reservation_date,
B.seated,
C.payment
from (#Reservation A
inner join #Reservation_details B
on B.reservation_id = A.id
left join #Payment C
on C.reservation_id = B.reservation_id)
where B.reservation_date = '2017-12-08'
AND (B.seated =1 or  C.payment is null)
```

You can use COUNT function by using HAVING in WHERE clause , it should be last statement and after the GROUP BY clause