# How to compare smallint -1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to find out if **status_id** field value of **SQL smallint** is **-1** and and get the records that doesn't have -1 for that field. My stored proc content is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7
        cs.case_id,
        cs.status_id,
        cm.company_name, 
        cs.created_time,
        cs.severity_id,
        cs.last_updated_time,
        COALESCE(NULLIF(cs.priority,''), 'Medium') AS case_priority
    FROM 
        tblcase cs with (nolock)
        INNER JOIN tblcompany cm with (nolock) ON (cs.company_id=cm.company_id)

    WHERE 
        CONVERT(INT, cs.status_id) <> -1  AND
        (cs.cas_case_owner = @userId AND cs.is_notify_co = 1) OR
        (cs.activity_owner = @userId AND cs.is_notify_ao = 1)

    ORDER BY cs.severity_id DESC, cs.case_id ASC
```

I have tried `CONVERT(int, cs.status_id) <> -1)`, `cs.status_id <> CONVERT(smallint, -1)`, `cs.status_id != CAST('-1' AS smallint)` and more, but I still keep getting records with -1 as the status_id. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong before downvoting.

Comment: Why you need to convert to `INT`? Can you please provide table structure and sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to use brackets for `OR` operation

```
cs.status_id <> -1 AND
     ( -- open
        (cs.cas_case_owner = @userId AND cs.is_notify_co = 1) 
        OR
        (cs.activity_owner = @userId AND cs.is_notify_ao = 1)
     ) -- close
```

See my another answer about it here - [SQL Server Left Join Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713482/sql-server-left-join-counting/47713634#47713634)

Comment: Yes! I have missed the brackets. What a silly mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It happens. )) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7
        cs.case_id,
        cs.status_id,
        cm.company_name, 
        cs.created_time,
        cs.severity_id,
        cs.last_updated_time,
        COALESCE(NULLIF(cs.priority,''), 'Medium') AS case_priority
    FROM 
        tblcase cs with (nolock)
        INNER JOIN tblcompany cm with (nolock) ON (cs.company_id=cm.company_id)

    WHERE ISNULL(CAST(cs.status_id AS INT),0)<> -1 
        AND cs.is_notify_co = 1
        AND
        (
            cs.cas_case_owner = @userId 
            OR
            cs.activity_owner = @userId 
        )
    ORDER BY cs.severity_id DESC, cs.case_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7
        cs.case_id,
        cs.status_id,
        cm.company_name, 
        cs.created_time,
        cs.severity_id,
        cs.last_updated_time,
        COALESCE(NULLIF(cs.priority,''), 'Medium') AS case_priority
    FROM 
        tblcase cs with (nolock)
        INNER JOIN tblcompany cm with (nolock) ON (cs.company_id=cm.company_id)

        WHERE 
            (
              ( cs.status_id <> -1  AND cs.cas_case_owner = @userId) AND 
              ( (cs.is_notify_co = 1) OR (cs.is_notify_ao = 1))
            )

    ORDER BY cs.severity_id DESC, cs.case_id ASC
```